# How to leverage slick effects to implicitly infer which of the DB instances to use Replica or Primary

Tags: scala, types, slick

We are using two databases: **primary and replica.**

**Use Case:**

- We want to provide an object that can be used to run DBIOAction (s), and be able to infer which database to use based on slick effects. 
  Reads => Replica.
  Writes => Primary.
- I also want to allow the programmer to pin the primary DB for reads but not replica to writes. I want to get a compilation error if someone tries to pin the replica to a read operation.

I have the following code:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
import Effect._
import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound

object DatabaseModule {
  // Used to create a constraint on what Role can an effect have.
  trait Role[E <: Effect]
  type ReplicaRole = Role[Read]
  type PrimaryRole = Role[Write] with ReplicaRole

  // database configuration depends on the role.
  sealed trait DatabaseConfiguration[R <: Role[_]] {
    def createDatabase(): Database
  }

  object DatabaseConfiguration {
    object Primary extends DatabaseConfiguration[PrimaryRole] {
      def createDatabase(): Database = Database.forConfig("slick.mysql.write")
    }
    object Replica extends DatabaseConfiguration[ReplicaRole] {
      def createDatabase(): Database = Database.forConfig("slick.mysql.read")
    }
  }

  class DB[R <: Role[_]](databaseConfiguration: DatabaseConfiguration[R]){
    val underlyingDatabase = databaseConfiguration.createDatabase()
  }

  object DB {
    // this error will be returned if the implicit is not found.
    @implicitNotFound("'${R}' database is not privileged to to perform effect '${E}'.")
    trait HasPrivilege[R <: Role[E], E <: Effect]

    // phantom types safe to assign null, used to enforce typing.
    implicit val replicaCanRead: ReplicaRole HasPrivilege Read = _
    implicit val primaryCanWrite: PrimaryRole HasPrivilege Write = _
    implicit val primaryCanRead: PrimaryRole HasPrivilege Read = _

    // primary and replica databases.
    implicit lazy val dbPrimary: DB[PrimaryRole] = new DB(DatabaseConfiguration.Primary)
    implicit lazy val dbReplica: DB[ReplicaRole] = new DB(DatabaseConfiguration.Replica)

    // this function should infer which configuration to use (primary for writes, replica for reads)
    def run[A, E <: Effect](a: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E])(implicit defaultDb: DB[Role[E]], p: Role[E] HasPrivilege E)
    : Future[A] = defaultDb.underlyingDatabase.run(a)

    // If we want to pin to replica, use this as follow DB.run(dbioAction)(dbMaster)
    def run[A, E <: Effect](a: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E])(db: Database)(implicit p: Role[E] HasPrivilege E)
    : Future[A] = db.run(a)
  }
}
```

However this is not working, when I try using it I get the following sbt errors

```scala
[error]   [A, E <: slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.Effect](a: slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.DBIOAction[A,slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.NoStream,E])(db: slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.Database)(implicit p: com.hautelook.support.db.mysql.DatabaseModule.DB.HasPrivilege[com.hautelook.support.db.mysql.DatabaseModule.Role[E],E])scala.concurrent.Future[A] <and>
[error]   [A, E <: slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.Effect](a: slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.DBIOAction[A,slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.NoStream,E])(implicit defaultDb: com.hautelook.support.db.mysql.DatabaseModule.DB[com.hautelook.support.db.mysql.DatabaseModule.Role[E]], implicit p: com.hautelook.support.db.mysql.DatabaseModule.DB.HasPrivilege[com.hautelook.support.db.mysql.DatabaseModule.Role[E],E])scala.concurrent.Future[A]
[error]  cannot be applied to (slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Int,Any,slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api.Effect.Write])
```

Anyone has an idea on how to resolve these types correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my answer is exactly what you want, but it seems to me close enough.

The immediate reasons of the compilation error is that the two `run` calls are indistinguishable to the compiler when called the way you want. The thing is that if you have two methods:

```
def foo(p1:Int):Int 
def foo(p1:Int)(p2:Int):Int
```

and a call

```
foo(1)
```

the compiler doesn't know if it is the full call of the `foo#1` or a partial application of the `foo#2`. Both choices look totally valid to the compiler. And even if you fix that I don't think you can easily make your first `run` work.

The main idea in my solution is that for the first `run` signature, the one that selects the default DB, to work you need some implicit mapping from the `Effect` onto the `DatabaseConfiguration`. The second `run` signature, that just verifies if the DB can run such a query, is done pretty the same way as in your solution. Here is full code

```
object DatabaseModule {

  sealed trait DatabaseConfiguration {
    lazy val underlyingDatabase: Database = createDatabase()

    protected def createDatabase(): Database
  }

  object PrimaryDb extends DatabaseConfiguration {
    def createDatabase(): Database = Database.forConfig("slick.mysql.write")
  }

  object ReplicaDb extends DatabaseConfiguration {
    def createDatabase(): Database = Database.forConfig("slick.mysql.read")
  }

  @implicitNotFound("'No default mapping for to perform effect '${E}'.")
  sealed case class DefaultDbMapping[E <: Effect] private(dbConfig: DatabaseConfiguration)

  object DefaultDbMapping {
    implicit val replicaIsDefaultRead = DefaultDbMapping[Read](ReplicaDb)

    // write goes to the primary
    implicit val primaryIsDefaultWrite = DefaultDbMapping[Write](PrimaryDb)
    // everything except for Read goes to the primary
    // implicit def primaryIsDefaultForEverythingElse[E <: Effect] = DefaultDbMapping[E](PrimaryDb)
  }


  object DB {

    // this error will be returned if the implicit is not found.
    @implicitNotFound("'${D}' database is not privileged to to perform effect '${E}'.")
    trait HasPrivilege[D <: DatabaseConfiguration, E <: Effect]

    // phantom types safe to assign null, used to enforce typing.
    implicit val replicaCanRead: ReplicaDb.type HasPrivilege Read = null
    implicit val primaryCanWrite: PrimaryDb.type HasPrivilege Write = null
    implicit val primaryCanRead: PrimaryDb.type HasPrivilege Read = null

    // this function should infer which configuration to use (primary for writes, replica for reads)
    def run[A, E <: Effect](a: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E])(implicit defaultDb: DefaultDbMapping[E]): Future[A] = defaultDb.dbConfig.underlyingDatabase.run(a)

    // You have some choices for the second run:
    // join 2 parameters so the compiler sees the difference between run(q) and run(q,db)
    def run[A, E <: Effect, D <: DatabaseConfiguration](a: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E], db: D)(implicit p: D HasPrivilege E): Future[A] = db.underlyingDatabase.run(a)
    // put the DB as the first parameter
    def run[A, E <: Effect, D <: DatabaseConfiguration](db: D)(a: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E])(implicit p: D HasPrivilege E): Future[A] = db.underlyingDatabase.run(a)
    // rename method to by explicitly different 
    def runOn[A, E <: Effect, D <: DatabaseConfiguration](db: D)(a: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E])(implicit p: D HasPrivilege E): Future[A] = db.underlyingDatabase.run(a)
  }
}
```

At the end I provide a few alternatives on how to fix your compilation issue as well. Choose whichever you like.

One more choice is to move the second method `run` to the `DatabaseConfiguration` like so:

```
  sealed trait DatabaseConfiguration {
    lazy val underlyingDatabase: Database = createDatabase()

    protected def createDatabase(): Database

    import DB._
    def run[A, E <: Effect](a: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E])(implicit p: this.type HasPrivilege E): Future[A] = underlyingDatabase.run(a)
  }
```

So you have a choice of 3 calls: `DB.run(query)`, `PrimaryDb.run(query)` and `ReplicaDb.run(query)`. In this case it might make sense to rename `DB` to something like `DefaultDb` so the calls look more natural.